# Как сделать вложеность html inline тегов после компиляции jade?

Tags: html, jade

Kод на jade:

```
.thumbnail
    .thumbnail-inner
        a(href="#")
            img(src="img-1.jpg")
            span.overlay
```

Компилирует:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail-inner"><a href="#"><img src="img-1.jpg"><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
</div>
```

А нужно :

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img-1.jpg">
            <span class="overlay"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Результат компиляции и то, что вам нужно это одно и тоже. Jade записал код

```
<div class="thumbnail-inner">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img-1.jpg">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

в виде строки

```
<div class="thumbnail-inner"><a href="#"><img src="img-1.jpg"><span class="overlay"></span></a><div>
```

на отображение в браузере это никак не повлияет.

Если вы все же хотите переносы, у jade есть опция pretty, которая в значение true добавляет отступы.

Например, в gulp это будет выглядеть так (pug это новое название jade)

```
.pipe(pug({
  pretty: true
}))
```

Результат компиляции с pretty: true будет повторять переносы из jade-файла.

Полный список опций: http://jade-lang.com/api/

Comment: Переносов не будет если это инлайн элементы. Опция pretty включена.